# Using the same `WiFi` - not able to access the localhost of my desktop in to smartphone

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ip

I have a application which is running in my laptop as `localhost:3000/xyz`. My laptop and smartphone both are using the same `WiFi` server.

I am trying to access my desktop localhost in my smartphone using the ip address like

`192.168.0.172:3000/xyz` - but I am getting error as

`192.168.0.172 too long to respond` or `access denied`

What is the wrong here? Or what is the correct way to access?

By the way:

my laptop shows the details like this on ipconfig:

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.172
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

my smartphone shows like this:

```
Ip address : 192.168.0.195
Subnet mask : 225.225.225.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Localhost don't need wi-fi (It's not even sending the data out to the network). If you cut the internet the localhost will still be there. As far as I know you cannot access to your localhost from another device. 192.168 etc. is your local network not your localhost.

Comment: I agree with you. can you show any work-around or plug-in for this?

Comment: @3gwebtrain Foun this article, it may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network
But it would be better if we know what you exactly want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is accessable even if the firewall is active on your PC blocking all incoming connections from your smartphone. So deactivate the firewall to test at first.